# subgraph changed alignment when put into a cluster

Tags: graphviz

The graph I would like contains a top row; the rightmost node (T3) then points to A. A through E are in a vertical column, C and F are vertically aligned and H, I and J are vertically aligned. Additionally, C, F and H are horizontally aligned and E, G and J are horizontally aligned.

When I add subgraph cluster_0 in front of the already existing subgraphs, i.e. subgraph cluster_0 { rank=same; A -> B -> C-> D-> E; }, the subgraph becomes horizontally aligned...

How can I introduce the cluster without this occurring? Also, the edge from T3 to A is nearly straight. I would be nice if it went straight down, right angled to the left then right angled down to A.

Here is what works:

```
digraph G { rankdir = LR ranksep = 1.2 nodesep = 0.5
  T1 -> T2 -> T3;
  { rank=same; A -> B -> C -> D -> E;  }
  C -> F
  { rank=same F -> G[style=invis] }
  E->G
  { rankdir=LR rank=same H -> I -> J}
  F -> H [style=dotted]
  G -> J [style=invis]
  edge [constraint=false]
  T3->A
}
```

And here is what doesn't work

```
digraph G { rankdir = LR ranksep = 1.2 nodesep = 0.5
  T1 -> T2 -> T3;
  subgraph cluster_0 { rank=same; A -> B -> C -> D -> E;  }
  C -> F
  subgraph cluster_1 { rank=same F -> G[style=invis] }
  E->G
  subgraph cluster_2 { rankdir=LR rank=same H -> I -> J}
  F -> H [style=dotted]
  G -> J [style=invis]
  edge [constraint=false]
  T3->A
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is about as close as I can get, but the clusters definitely introduce some differences.  Also the "almost straight" lines I corrected with `splines=ortho`.  I moved the ABCDE subgraph over with an invisible edge to T1.

```
digraph G { rankdir=TB ranksep = 0.5 nodesep = 0.5 splines=ortho
  {rank=same T1 -> T2 -> T3;}

T1->A [style=invis]

  subgraph cluster_0 {rank=min  A -> B -> C -> D -> E;  }
  C -> F
  subgraph cluster_1 { rank=same F -> G[style=invis] }
  E->G
  subgraph cluster_2 { rankdir=LR rank=same H -> I -> J}
  F -> H [style=dotted]
  G -> J [style=invis]
  edge [constraint=false]
  T3->A
}
```